# Livekd documentation and tutorials

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, sos, livekd

I know LiveKd is a tool to create dumps for analysis.

Can someone help me with some links that help me learn how to use LiveKd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveKD is a sysinternals application that sits on top of WinDbg and kd so a lot of the output is the same but it provides live updating so I agree with snoone and his recommendations. You are recommended to seek out Windows Internals, Advanced Windows Debugging, Windows Debugging Notebook and the following websites: http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/

Answer (score 5):

The absolute best starting point is the Windows Internals book. Read it from front to back and follow the WinDBG related examples included, all of which use LiveKD in some way.

Though, in the end, working with LiveKD is (effectively) the same as analyzing a full memory dump in WinDBG. Thus, you'll find a lot of information by searching around for WinDBG tutorials. Then you can come back with more specific questions about what you're trying to analyze. As a starting point, I have a column in The NT Insider called, "Analyst's Perspective" where I cover lots of WinDBG related things:

http://www.osronline.com/section.cfm?section=17

And I try to cover a broad range of WinDBG debugging related topics on my blog (http://analyze-v.com)

Comment: The link to your blog does not seem to be functional anymore. If there is a new URL, it would be great if you could update the link.